# Prove that a "set of all sets" does not exist.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Axiom I used for the proof:

**The Axiom Schema of Comprehension**: Let **P**$(x)$ be a property of $x$. For any set $A$, there is a set $B$ such that $x\in B$ if and only if $x\in A$ and **P**$(x)$.

Here is my attempt:

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the set of all sets indeed exist and we call it $V$. Now consider the property **P**$(x)$: $x\notin x$. Then by the Comprehension Schema, there exists a set $X$ in which $x\in X$ if and only if $x\in V$ and **P**$(x)$; i.e.,
\begin{align*}
                x\in X\iff x\in V\text{ and }x\notin x.
            \end{align*}
Since $V$ is the set of all sets and $X$ is a set, then we must have $X\in V$. If $X\in V$ then either $X\in X$ or $X\notin X$. If $X\in X$ then we have
\begin{align*}
                X\in X\iff X\in V\text{ and }X\notin X,
            \end{align*}
a contradiction. Now if $X\notin X$ then
\begin{align*}
                X\notin X\iff X\notin V\text{ or }X\in X,
            \end{align*}
but if $X\notin V$, then we are done. Now if $X\in X$, this again yield a contradiction. In either case, a contradiction. Therefore $X\notin V$, and thus the set of all sets does not exist.

is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.

You can actually rephrase your proof and make it constructive. Doing so only slightly modified the proof. Instead of doing case analysis on whether $X \in X$, we can phrase this step of the proof as follows:

Suppose $X \in X$. In that case, we would have $X \notin X$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, we must have $X \notin X$.

Now we have $X \notin X$. We also trivially have $X \in V$. Therefore, $X \in X$. This is a contradiction. Therefore, there must not be any such set $V$. $\square$

Comment: We could also go from, $\forall x,x\in X\Leftrightarrow x\in V\land x\notin x$ to $X\in X\Leftrightarrow X\notin X$ in basically just one step, since $x\in V$ is always true by definition of $V$ and since we can specify $x$ to be $X$. And $X\in X\Leftrightarrow X\notin X$ is a contradiction (it's something iff its negation).